# MX Datagrids Sort- Case Sensitive by Default

Tags: apache-flex

Is it just me, or do flex MX datagrids sort in a case sensitive manner be default? That is, they'll sort like this:

- A
- A
- B
- B
- C
- C
- a
- a
- b
- c
- c

I know I can give a datagrid column a custom sort function, but do I really have to do that for every column in the app?

So this is a bug in a legacy app- updating every single grid to spark really isn't an option (if that's even a fix). Am I missing some obvious way to change the sorting pattern for an entire grid? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a sub-class of `DataGridColumn` and specify the sort function there. Use that class in all grids you need to avoid copy-paste.